# About a/the definition of plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

> Let $P$ be a point in 3-space and consider a located vector $ \overrightarrow {0N}$. We define the plane passing through $P$ perpendicular to $ \overrightarrow {0N}$ to be the collection of all points $X$ such that the located vector $ \overrightarrow {PX}$ is perpendicular to $ \overrightarrow {0N}$. This amounts to the condition $(X - P) \cdot N = 0$ or $X \cdot N = P \cdot N$.

My question has to do with $X$. On the one hand, $X$ is a collection of all points for which a certain property is true. So, $X$ is basically a plane. But since $ \overrightarrow {PX}$ is a located vector, $X$ also must be a single point.

Do you think they have used the same variable to denote two different things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, $X$ is always just one point in the plane.

The quote does not give any name to the plane (or *collection* of points) itself.

You should parse it as "the collection of all [points $X$ such that ...]", not "[the collection of all points] $X$".